# Android - How to reserve more memory to a specific activity?

Tags: android, memory-management, heap-memory

### The problem

I have an activity that communicate with a wifi camera through a socket connection (the connection logic cannot be changed because I am using Sony wifi camera SDK).
When this activity is launched as the first (even as the secondo should work) activity everytime is going correctly, the live view is smooth and I'm happy.

When I have 4-5 activities behind the "camera "activity" that starts become very slow and an hard frame lag appears.

So I think that the camera activity must have more priority than the other activities and use more memory.

### Question

In relation with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24200852/android-sony-wifi-camera-qx10-frame-lag-while-having-multiple-activity-up), is it possible to set an higher priority to a specific activity for letting it use more heap memory than a standard activity?

Comment: You should put the details of your needs into this question as the information in the linked question or this one may change over time and become inaccurate or invalid.

Comment: You are right, I have done the job